# Let $f(x_1, x_2)$ be a term in a first order language $L$; call this term $t$. Decide if $t$ is free for $x_1$ in the following formula of $L$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Definition:
>   $\varphi$ a formula, $t$ a term. We say "$t$ is free for $x_i$ in $\varphi$ **if no free occurence of $x_i$ in $\varphi$ lies within the scope of $\forall x_j$ where $x_j$ is a variable appearing in $t$**

I somehow couldn't understand this definition fully.

Can anyone help me with this by an example:

Let $f(x_1, x_2)$ be a term in a first order language $L$; call this term $t$. Decide if $t$ is free for $x_1$ in the following formula of $L$:

$R(x_1, x_2) \rightarrow (\forall x_2)S(x_2)$

I think $t$ is free for $x_1$ here, because the occurrence of $x_1$ does not lie in the scope of any quantifier of the form $\exists x_j$ or $\forall x_j$

Am I right?

Comment: Did you change from  $x_i $ to $x_j $ in the definition on purpose?

Comment: It's the way it's defined

Comment: @RGS: the definition would be nonsensical if you changed $x_j$ to $x_i$: an occurrence of $x_i$ in the scope of $\forall x_i$ is by definition not a free occurrence.

Comment: @RobArthan it does make a lot of sense now, after reading your explanation. I only asked because I learned this not so long ago, but couldn't remember the intuitive meaning of the definition. If I had remembered, I couldn't have explained it better than you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, although you should say that the occurrence of $x_1$ only occurs in the scope of quantifiers $\forall x_j$ where $j \neq 1$.

I have always found this terminology a bit counter-intuitive, but the idea is that "$t$ is free for $x_i$ in $\phi$" means that you can simply replace each free occurrence of $x_i$ in $\phi$ by $t$ and get a new formula that "says the same thing about $t$ as $\phi$ said about $x_i$". This means that no free variable $x_j$ of $t$ is allowed to be "captured" by a quantifier in $\phi$.

For example, if $t$ is $x_1 + x_2$ and $\phi$ is
$$(\forall x_2(x_3 \ge x_2)) \lor (\forall x_4(x_5 \ge x_4)$$
$t$ is not free for $x_3$ in $\phi$, but $t$ is free for $x_5$ in $\phi$. If you replace $x_3$ by $t$, you get:

$$(\forall x_2(x_1 + x_2 \ge x_2)) \lor (\forall x_4(x_5 \ge x_4)$$

which (over the natural numbers) is true, while $\phi$ is false for any values of its free variables $x_3$ and $x_5$. So the replacement isn't making the same statement about $t$ as $\phi$ makes about $x_3$.
However, if you replace $x_5$ by $t$, you get

$$(\forall x_2(x_3 \ge x_2)) \lor (\forall x_4(x_1 + x_2 \ge x_4)$$

which is making the same (false) statement about $t$ that $\phi$ makes about $x_5$.